# loading a file, posting that to a textbox

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I have got stuck on a problem, I have this GUI in wxpython, where i want to load in a file, and then i want to see the textfiles name in the textCtrl which has already been put onto the panel
here is my code

```
def __init__(self, parent):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, wx.NewId(), "Load PDB",size=(240,200))
    panel=wx.Panel(self)
    pdb = wx.Button(panel, label="Browse...", pos=(170,10), size=(53,25))
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.getPdb,pdb)
    wx.StaticText(panel,-1,"Load PDB", (5,15))
    hey=wx.TextCtrl(panel,-1,"",pos=(60,10), size=(100,25))

def getPdb(self,event):
      dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "Choose a file", os.getcwd(), "", "*.*", wx.OPEN)
      if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
               path = dlg.GetPath()
               mypath=os.path.basename(path)
      dlg.Destroy()
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: I'm not familiar with wxpython but should all the objects under `__init__` have `self.` appended to the front of them?

Comment: What have you tried? You can use wx.TextCtrl.write() if I understood the question correctly.

Comment: I've declared mypath as a global variable and passed it into the textCtrl as the text but it doesn't work

Comment: i'll try the write() now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As one of the comments mention, you'll have to assign a name in the **init** function to be an instance variable, so it's available in other scopes.  So do this first:

```
self.hey=wx.TextCtrl(panel,-1,"",pos=(60,10), size=(100,25))
```

Now we can use self.hey in your second method, getPdb:

```
def getPdb(self,event):
    dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "Choose a file", os.getcwd(), "", "*.*", wx.OPEN)
    mypath = ''
    if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        path = dlg.GetPath()
        mypath=os.path.basename(path)
    dlg.Destroy()

    if mypath:
        self.hey.Clear()
        self.hey.AppendText(mypath)
    return
```

Because of the height of your textctrl, I assumed you want to clear what's in there first. If that's not what you want, then remove the self.hey.Clear() line, add any separator (:, ;, \n) you want to mypath, and append that.